# How to Select specific tracks in Exoplayer latest release 2.18.0

Tags: android, android-studio, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I have tried the code from exoplayer documentation, it works but when I fetch selected track it shows the default track which I already changed.

```
player.setTrackSelectionParameters(
    player.getTrackSelectionParameters()
        .buildUpon()
        .setOverrideForType(
            new TrackSelectionOverride(
                audioTrackGroup.getMediaTrackGroup(),
                /* trackIndex= */ 0))
        .build());
```

The code I used before the latest release is:

```
    private fun setSubTrack(
        trackSelector: DefaultTrackSelector?,
        subLanguage: String
    ) {
        trackSelector?.setParameters(trackSelector.buildUponParameters()
            .setRendererDisabled(C.TRACK_TYPE_VIDEO, false)
            .setPreferredTextLanguage(subLanguage))
    }
```

This code worked perfectly. But from the latest release this code is not working. So i changed this with the above one.

My entire code to change tracks:

```
package ysports.app.player

import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.net.Uri
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.*
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.TrackSelectionOverride
import com.google.android.material.dialog.MaterialAlertDialogBuilder
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList
import ysports.app.PlayerActivity
import ysports.app.R
import ysports.app.api.fixture.Media
import java.util.*

class PlayerUtil {

    private var selectedAudioPosition = 0
    private var selectedAudioChoice = 0
    private var selectedSubPosition = 0
    private var selectedSubChoice = 0
    private var selectedVideoPosition = 1
    private var selectedVideoChoice = 1
    private var selectedSpeedPosition = 3
    private var selectedSpeedChoice = 3
    private var isVideoTrackAuto = true

    fun selectAudioTrack(
        context: Context,
        player: ExoPlayer?
    ) {
        val tracks = player?.currentTracks ?: return
        val audioTrackGroups = ArrayList<Tracks.Group>()
        val audioList = ArrayList<String>()

        audioList.add("Disable")

        for (trackGroup in tracks.groups) {
            // Group level information.
            val trackType: Int = trackGroup.type
            //val trackInGroupIsSelected = trackGroup.isSelected
            //val trackInGroupIsSupported = trackGroup.isSupported

            if (trackType == C.TRACK_TYPE_AUDIO) {
                audioTrackGroups.add(trackGroup)
                for (i in 0 until trackGroup.length) {
                    // Individual track information.
                    val isSupported = trackGroup.isTrackSupported(i)
                    val isSelected = trackGroup.isTrackSelected(i)
                    val trackFormat = trackGroup.getTrackFormat(i)

                    if (isSelected) {
                        selectedAudioPosition = i + 1
                        selectedAudioChoice = selectedAudioPosition
                    }
                    var label = if (trackFormat.label != null) " - ${trackFormat.label}" else ""
                    label += if (!isSupported) " (Unsupported)" else ""
                    val list = Locale(trackFormat.language.toString()).displayLanguage + label

                    if (list.contains("und") || list.contains("null")) audioList.add("Audio track #${i + 1}") else audioList.add(list)
                }
            }
        }

        val tempTracks = audioList.toArray(arrayOfNulls<CharSequence>(audioList.size))
        MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(context)
            .setTitle("Audio Track")
            .setNeutralButton(context.getString(R.string.cancel)) { _, _ -> }
            .setPositiveButton(context.getString(R.string.ok)) { _, _ ->
                selectedAudioPosition = selectedAudioChoice
                if (selectedAudioPosition == 0) {
                    setAudioTrack(player, audioTrackGroups[0], true)
                } else {
                    setAudioTrack(player, audioTrackGroups[selectedAudioPosition - 1], false)
                }
            }
            .setSingleChoiceItems(tempTracks, selectedAudioPosition) { _, position ->
                selectedAudioChoice = position
            }
            .show()
    }

    private fun setAudioTrack(
        player: ExoPlayer?,
        audioTrackGroup: Tracks.Group?,
        audioDisabled: Boolean
    ) {
        player?.trackSelectionParameters = player?.trackSelectionParameters!!
            .buildUpon()
            .setTrackTypeDisabled(C.TRACK_TYPE_AUDIO, audioDisabled)
            .setOverrideForType(
                TrackSelectionOverride(
                    audioTrackGroup?.mediaTrackGroup!!, 0
                )
            )
            .build()
    }

    fun selectSubTrack(
        context: Context,
        player: ExoPlayer?
    ) {
        val tracks = player?.currentTracks ?: return
        val textTrackGroups = ArrayList<Tracks.Group>()
        val subtitlesList = ArrayList<String>()

        subtitlesList.add("Disable")

        for (trackGroup in tracks.groups) {
            // Group level information.
            val trackType: Int = trackGroup.type
            //val trackInGroupIsSelected = trackGroup.isSelected
            //val trackInGroupIsSupported = trackGroup.isSupported

            if (trackType == C.TRACK_TYPE_TEXT) {
                textTrackGroups.add(trackGroup)
                for (i in 0 until trackGroup.length) {
                    // Individual track information.
                    val isSupported = trackGroup.isTrackSupported(i)
                    val isSelected = trackGroup.isTrackSelected(i)
                    val trackFormat = trackGroup.getTrackFormat(i)

                    if (isSelected) {
                        selectedSubPosition = i + 1
                        selectedSubChoice = selectedSubPosition
                    }
                    var label = if (trackFormat.label != null) " - ${trackFormat.label}" else ""
                    label += if (!isSupported) " (Unsupported)" else ""

                    subtitlesList.add(Locale(trackFormat.language.toString()).displayLanguage + label)
                }
            }
        }

        val tempTracks = subtitlesList.toArray(arrayOfNulls<CharSequence>(subtitlesList.size))
        MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(context)
            .setTitle("Subtitle")
            .setNeutralButton(context.getString(R.string.cancel)) { _, _ -> }
            .setPositiveButton(context.getString(R.string.ok)) { _, _ ->
                selectedSubPosition = selectedSubChoice
                if (selectedSubPosition == 0) {
                    setSubTrack(player, textTrackGroups[0], true)
                } else {
                    setSubTrack(player, textTrackGroups[selectedSubPosition - 1], false)
                }
            }
            .setSingleChoiceItems(tempTracks, selectedSubPosition) { _, position ->
                selectedSubChoice = position
            }
            .show()
    }

    private fun setSubTrack(
        player: ExoPlayer?,
        textTrackGroup: Tracks.Group?,
        textDisabled: Boolean
    ) {
        player?.trackSelectionParameters = player?.trackSelectionParameters!!
            .buildUpon()
            .setTrackTypeDisabled(C.TRACK_TYPE_TEXT, textDisabled)
            .setOverrideForType(
                TrackSelectionOverride(
                    textTrackGroup?.mediaTrackGroup!!, 0
                )
            )
            .build()
    }

    fun selectVideoTrack(
        context: Context,
        player: ExoPlayer?
    ) {
        val tracks = player?.currentTracks ?: return

        var group: Tracks.Group? = null
        val videoList = ArrayList<String>()

        videoList.add("Disable")
        videoList.add("Auto")

        for (trackGroup in tracks.groups) {
            // Group level information.
            val trackType: Int = trackGroup.type
            //val trackInGroupIsSelected = trackGroup.isSelected
            //val trackInGroupIsSupported = trackGroup.isSupported

            if (trackType == C.TRACK_TYPE_VIDEO) {
                group = trackGroup
                for (i in 0 until trackGroup.length) {
                    // Individual track information.
                    val isSupported = trackGroup.isTrackSupported(i)
                    val isSelected = trackGroup.isTrackSelected(i)
                    val trackFormat = trackGroup.getTrackFormat(i)

                    if (isSelected) {
                        selectedVideoPosition = i + 2
                        selectedVideoChoice = selectedVideoPosition
                    }
                    if (isVideoTrackAuto) {
                        selectedVideoPosition = 1
                        selectedVideoChoice = 1
                    }
                    var bitrate = ""
                    if (trackFormat.bitrate != -1) {
                        bitrate = String.format("- %.2f Mbps", trackFormat.bitrate * 0.000001)
                    }
                    val width = trackFormat.width
                    val height = trackFormat.height
                    val list = if (isSupported) "${width}x$height $bitrate" else "${width}x$height $bitrate (Unsupported)"

                    videoList.add(list)
                }
            }
        }

        val tempTracks = videoList.toArray(arrayOfNulls<CharSequence>(videoList.size))
        MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(context)
            .setTitle("Quality")
            .setNeutralButton(context.getString(R.string.cancel)) { _, _ -> }
            .setPositiveButton(context.getString(R.string.ok)) { _, _ ->
                selectedVideoPosition = selectedVideoChoice
                isVideoTrackAuto = false
                setVideoTrack(player, group, selectedVideoPosition)
            }
            .setSingleChoiceItems(tempTracks, selectedVideoPosition) { _, position ->
                selectedVideoChoice = position
            }
            .show()
    }

    private fun setVideoTrack(
        player: ExoPlayer?,
        videoTrackGroup: Tracks.Group?,
        trackIndex: Int
    ) {
        when (selectedVideoPosition) {
            0 -> {
                player?.trackSelectionParameters = player?.trackSelectionParameters!!
                    .buildUpon()
                    .setTrackTypeDisabled(C.TRACK_TYPE_VIDEO, true)
                    .build()
            }
            1 -> {
                isVideoTrackAuto = true
                player?.trackSelectionParameters = player?.trackSelectionParameters!!
                    .buildUpon()
                    .setTrackTypeDisabled(C.TRACK_TYPE_VIDEO, false)
                    .setMaxVideoSizeSd()
                    .build()
            }
            else -> {
                player?.trackSelectionParameters = player?.trackSelectionParameters!!
                    .buildUpon()
                    .setTrackTypeDisabled(C.TRACK_TYPE_VIDEO, false)
                    .setOverrideForType(
                        TrackSelectionOverride(
                            videoTrackGroup?.mediaTrackGroup!!, trackIndex - 2
                        )
                    )
                    .build()
            }
        }
    }

    fun setPlaybackSpeed(
        context: Context,
        player: ExoPlayer?
    ) {
        if (player == null) return
        val speedList = arrayOf("0.25", "0.5", "0.75", "Normal", "1.25", "1.5", "1.75", "2")
        val speed = floatArrayOf(0.25F, 0.5F, 0.75F, 1F, 1.25F, 1.5F, 1.75F, 2F)

        MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(context)
            .setTitle(context.getString(R.string.playback_speed))
            .setNeutralButton(context.getString(R.string.cancel)) { _, _ -> }
            .setPositiveButton(context.getString(R.string.ok)) { _, _ ->
                selectedSpeedPosition = selectedSpeedChoice
                player.setPlaybackSpeed(speed[selectedSpeedPosition])
            }
            .setSingleChoiceItems(speedList, selectedSpeedPosition) { _, position ->
                selectedSpeedChoice = position
            }
            .show()
    }
}
```

This code changes the audio, video and text tracks but **val isSelected = trackGroup.isTrackSelected(i)** is always return the default track.

Anyone know how to fix this problem!

Answer (score 0):

I am also struggling like you and trying to achieve the same thing.
So far I have found these..this is working but also had some problems if there are multiple trackGroups of the same type. e.g: audio

```
player?.let {
                    /*it.trackSelectionParameters = it.trackSelectionParameters
                        .buildUpon()
                        .setPreferredAudioLanguage(audioTracks[selectedAudioTrack])
                        .build()*/

                    it.trackSelectionParameters = it.trackSelectionParameters
                        .buildUpon()
                        .setTrackSelectionOverrides(
                            TrackSelectionOverrides
                                .Builder()
                                .addOverride(TrackSelectionOverrides.TrackSelectionOverride(
                                    audioTrackGroup!!, listOf(selectedAudioTrack)
                                ))
                                .build()
                        )
                        .build()
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
private fun selectAudioTrack() {
    val tracks = player?.currentTracks ?: return
    val audioTrackGroups = ArrayList<Tracks.Group>()
    val audioList = ArrayList<String>()
    audioList.add("None")
    var selected = 0

    for (trackGroup in tracks.groups) {
        // Group level information.
        val trackType: Int = trackGroup.type
        //val trackInGroupIsSelected = trackGroup.isSelected
        //val trackInGroupIsSupported = trackGroup.isSupported

        if (trackType == C.TRACK_TYPE_AUDIO) {
            audioTrackGroups.add(trackGroup)
            for (i in 0 until trackGroup.length) {
                // Individual track information.
                val isSupported = trackGroup.isTrackSupported(i)
                val isSelected = trackGroup.isTrackSelected(i)
                val trackFormat = trackGroup.getTrackFormat(i)
                selected++
                if (isSelected) {
                    selectedAudioPosition = selected
                }
                Log.d("track", "$isSupported $isSelected $trackFormat $selectedAudioPosition")

                var label = if (trackFormat.label != null) " - ${trackFormat.label}(${
                    formatNameFromMime(trackFormat.sampleMimeType)
                })" else ""
                label += if (!isSupported) " (Unsupported)" else ""
                val list = Locale(trackFormat.language.toString()).displayLanguage + label

                if (list.contains("und") || list.contains("null")) audioList.add("Audio track #${i + 1}") else audioList.add(
                    list
                )
            }
        }
    }

    
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)